# Build an XML with a custom settings for migration in salesforce org to org

Tags: customsetting, migration

I have to create a package XML for migrating two Custom Settings (say A,B) from one org to another.

I have a sample for a Report Type but what should be the case for two Custom settings?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>TOT_Reporting_abv</members>
        <name>ReportType</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>Abbott_Rep_Reports/TOT_Reports_abv</members>
        <name>Report</name>
    </types>
   <version>36.0</version>
</Package>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are ordinary [CustomObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/customobject.htm) entries, just as if you were migrating fields from Account or MyCustomObject__c.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>CustomSetting1__c</members>
        <members>CustomSetting2__c</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
   <version>36.0</version>
</Package>
```